# Cohomology of quotient stack

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, algebraic-stacks, equivariant-cohomology

Let $X$ be an algebraic variety over $\mathbb{C}$ (the ground field is not important but this makes things easier I think) and $G$ an algebraic group acting over it. Let's say we know that there's a normal subgroup $K \cong \mathbb{G}_m$ such that $K$ acts trivially on $X$ and $G/K$ acts in a free way on $X$.

I think one could put less restrictive hypothesis on $K$ actually: maybe reductive should be enough.

I'm denoting as $\mathcal{X}=[X/G]$ the quotient stack. Is it always true that $$H^*(\mathcal{X}) \cong H^*(X/(G/K)) \otimes H^*(BK) $$ and $$H^*_c(\mathcal{X}) \cong H^*_c(X/(G/K)) \otimes H^*_c(BK)  $$
(everything is meant to be with $\overline{\mathbb{Q}_{\ell}}$ coefficients.

What should be a possible counterexample?

Comment: If $X = \operatorname{Spec}\mathbb C$, you're asking for an isomorphism $H^*(BG)\cong H^*(BG/K)\otimes H^*(BK)$, which in general does not exist - you only have the Lyndon-Hochschild-Serre spectral sequence. For general $X$, a similar construction should give you a spectral sequence with $E^2$-page $H^*([X/(G/K)])\otimes H^*(BK)$ convergin to $H^*(\mathcal X)$.

Comment: I've edited sorry. If I add the addictionally hypothesis on the  $G/K$ action?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $G$ be a linear algebraic group, and $K\subset G$ a closed normal subgroup with quotient $L = G/K$. So all three groups are linear algebraic. Further, assume $L$ is connected.

Let $X$ be a variety with $G$-action such that $K$ acts trivially, $L$ acts freely and we have a quotient $X/L$.

**Step 1:**  The canonical map $BG \to BL$ is a fiber bundle with fiber $BK$. As $L$ is connected the mondromy action on the cohomology of the fibers, namely $H^*(BK)$, is trivial. Further, the Leray-Serre spectral sequence associated to this fiber bundle degenerates at $E_2$ because both $BK$ and $BL$ have cohomology concentrated in even degrees.

Note: The claim about odd vanishing in cohomology holds because $K$ and $L$ are linear algebraic groups and we are using torsion free coefficients (it is ultimately due to the Bruhat decomposition). To emphasize: no connected assumptions are needed for this vanishing, just torsion free coefficients and linear algebraic groups.

**Step 2:**  We have a pullback square (this **claim** should be checked - I have not worked out the details carefully):
$\require{AMScd}$
\begin{CD}
[X/G] @>{}>> BG\\
@VVV @VVV\\
X/L @>{}>> BL
\end{CD}

The monodromy action on the cohomology of the fibers $H^*(BK)$ for the bundle $[X/G] \to X/L$ is the pullback of the monodromy action in $BG \to BL$. Hence, it is trivial.

Further, the elements of $H^*(BK)$ are permanent cycles in the Leray-Serre spectral sequence of $[X/G] \to X/L$ because they are so for that of $BG \to BL$. This gives the required claim:

$H^*([X/G]) \cong H^*(BK) \otimes H^*(X/L)$.

Note: even assuming I haven't done something completely dumb above, this says nothing about ring structure. Further, the requirement that $L$ act freely on $X$ should be unnecessary - replace $X/L$ by $[X/L]$ (again, modulo me not being delusional).

The point (assuming the pullback square is correct) at the heart of the matter is that $BG \to BL$ is the **universal** example of a fiber bundle with structure group $G$ in which the $G$-action on the fibers factors through $L$ (i.e., $K$ acts trivially).

Comment: Could you explain step 2 better? I do not understand why the degeneration of one spectral sequence should imply the degeneration of the other (all I can see is that the image of $H^*(BL)$ in $H^*(X/L)$ has to be composed by permanent cycles, but that map does not need to be surjective...)

Comment: @DenisNardin: $H^*(BG)$ surjects onto the cohomology of the fiber $H^*(BK)$, hence $H^*([X/G])$ surjects onto the cohomology of the fiber $H^*(BK)$. Now Leray-Hirsch. Or did I do something screwy?

Comment: Oh yeah, I had my differentials going in the wrong direction (too many homological SS, I guess :)). This should work. I still think you could add a couple of words of explanation to your answer.

Comment: @rvk I actually did not get why from the degeneration of the spectral sequence we get the tensor product equality. The spectral sequence should be $E^{p,q}_2=H^p(X/L,R^qf_*\mathbb{Q}_{\ell})$ and so one gets $$E^{p,q}_2=H^p(X/L,R^qf_*\mathbb{Q}_{\ell}) =H^{p+q}([X/G],\mathbb{Q}_{\ell})$$ . Shouldn't one check also that $ R^qf_*\mathbb{Q}_{\ell}$ are trivial local systems? Is this implied by the surjection $ H([X/G]) \to H(BK)$?

Comment: @rvk Also do you think that this works for cohomology with compact support too? Your argument seems to generalize but I'm starting to get a little bit lost ...

Comment: @TommasoScognamiglio : You are indeed right to worry about monodromy on the fiber. The easy cheat is to throw in the assumption that $L$ is connected (this will force the monodromy action on $R^qf_* \mathbb{Q}_{\ell}$ in the space $X/L$ to be trivial since it is the pullback of the monodromy action of $\pi_1(BL) = 0$).

If you dont want that assumption ($L$ connected) then the formulae will be messier, but should be tractable. Roughly, since we are in torsion free coefficients, one will see invariants of the component group $L/L_0$ show up.

Comment: @TommasoScognamiglio : As to$H^*_c$, I haven't thought about it (so take what I say now with an even bigger dollop of salt), but there shouldn't be any issues due to the following `trick': although the spaces $BG$, $BL$ involved are a stacky/infinite dimensional, their cohomology (up to arbitrarily high degree) and these fibrations can be approximated by honest varieties (Steifel varieties) which are smooth+projective. So usual Poincare duality applies (ok, there might be some trouble if $X$ is nasty - but in that case $H^*_c$ is probably a bad thing to look at anyway).

Comment: However, note that I don't generally like statements that involve $H^*_c(BK)$ - what does that term even mean (in general)?. The $!$-pushforward to a point from this sort of `space' needs a bit of care (ditto if you go into Verdier duality land and Borel-Moore homology).

Comment: @rvk thank you for the explanation of triviliaty of monodromy. I was more or less thinking about compactly supported cohomology for algebraic stacks which (altough not pleasant) should be defined generally. (I don't want to say some uncorrect stuff but I think there should be a whole story of six functors also for Artin stacks). My problem in this case is that I can't see how to define a natural  morphism $H_c(BG) \to H_c(BK)$. If I understood what you suggesting is that we look at geometric realizations of these objects and  go on from this.

Comment: This should actually not be extendable to $[X/G]$ if $X$ is not smooth, isn't it? (It's highly likely I'm missing something due to stacky stuff and my poor knowledge of the subject)

Comment: @TommasoScognamiglio : There is a full formalism of 6-functors for Artin stacks (eg. Laszlo-Olsson papers). However, there is no need to invoke the full power of it for these Qs that only involve cohomology with local system coefficients (or even intersection cohomology). There are two ways to do this: you can either use approximations to these stacks (as I alluded to in my earlier comment). Or if you are over $\mathbb{C}$ you can use simplicial varieties to convert the whole question to pure topology.

I don't see why $X$ not being smooth is a problem for generalizing to $[X/G]$. Explain?

Comment: In the compact support setting shouldn't we look up to the same spectral sequence but with $f_!$ instead? In this case I can see why the same triviality statement should be true

Comment: @TommasoScognamiglio: The issue with $f_!$ is this: how do you define it for a map of the form $[BK] \to \ast$? When I said full formalism of 6-functors for stacks, I should have been clearer: full formalism for representable morphisms. So before we can even talk about spectral sequence there is a bit of an issue in making sense of $f_!$. Maybe it is not a problem, but I would be a bit careful. You can raise the same objections with $f_*$, but those I know how to get around. Not so sure about $f_!$. I am confessing to ignorance more than anything else.

Comment: I'm actually citing stuff I know little about, but in the article by Laszlo-Olsoon https://math.berkeley.edu/~molsson/article-Iweb.pdf they seem to not work with representable morphisms (at least If I understood). What I didn't get is: without getting messy with $f_!$ and just looking at approximation of stacks (or simplicial situation), how do I show a similar statement for cohomology with compact support? Sorry I didn't get this

Comment: @TommasoScognamiglio: While you have accepted the answer, I will confess that I don't have a clean statement for you in the compactly supported setting. I think there is no problem, but the argument sketch in my head involves working with approximations/in the equivariant derived category and using the Decomposition Theorem for the pushforward in question to show a tensor product at the level of sheaves on $X/L$ (as opposed to spectral sequences). This seems like overkill to me. However, unfortunately I don't quite have the time to figure out a clean elementary argument. Sorry!

Comment: No problem! I still thought your answer to be very clear and well written and I didn't want you to lose the bounty!

Comment: Hi. COming back to you quite a long time after, but looking back at your answer I'm not able to see right now why the monodromy of the local systems on $X/L$ should be the pullback of that on $BL$ (and actually how to talk about monodromy for stacks). Sorry to come back at this after so much time, but this question came back to my mind recently